# Issue on a form using jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm building a small kind-of "sliding" form template using jQuery and I'm stuck on something that must probably be very silly.

There's some light validation going on in the script file, basically disabling the "next" button initially, and then enabling it once you answered the question (be it a radio, checkbox or text input).

The form gets stuck on the second question (the next button never gets enabled), even if I switch the first two `<li>` elements. Here's a jsfiddle. I'd be grateful if you could make me stop banging my head on the wall.

https://jsfiddle.net/ntnr/6szynjqj/1/

HTML

```
<ul id="rom">
      <li class="active">
        <div class="form-group checkbox-group" required>
            <h3>CHECKBOX! What is Your Favorite Pet? (1)</h3>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" name="pet" value="cat">Cats</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" name="pet" value="dog">Dogs</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" name="pet" value="rabbit">Rabbits</label>
            </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="form-group radio-group" required>
            <h3>RADIO! What is Your Favorite Book? (2)</h3>
            <div class="radio">
              <label><input type="radio" name="book" value="this">This one</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
              <label><input type="radio" name="book" value="that">That one</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
              <label><input type="radio" name="book" value="other">The other one</label>
            </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="form-group input-group" required>
            <h3>INPUT! What is Your Favorite Time of the Day? (3)</h3>
            <div class="input">
              <label><input #superbutton type="input" name="time" value="morning"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
      </li>
        </ul>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var prev_button = $('<button class="btn prev" style="margin-right:5px;">Prev</button>');
var next_button = $('<button class="btn next" disabled>Next</button>');

$('#rom > li').append(prev_button);
$('#rom > li').append(next_button);
$('#rom > li').first().find('button.prev').hide();
$('#rom > li').last().find('button.next').hide();

$('.prev').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).closest('li').prev().addClass('active');
});

$('.next').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).closest('li').next().addClass('active');
});

// Validation (non-empty) for Input fields
$('.input-group input').keyup(function() {
    var empty = false;
    $('.field input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
            empty = true;
        }
    });
    if (empty) {
        $(this).closest(button.next).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $(this).closest(button.next).attr('disabled', false);
    }
});

// Validation (non-empty) for Checkboxes
var checkBoxes = $('#rom > li.active').find('.checkbox-group input[type="checkbox"]');
checkBoxes.change(function () {
  $(this).closest('li').find('button.next').prop('disabled', checkBoxes.filter(':checked').length < 1);
});
$('.checkbox-group input[type="checkbox"]').change();

// Validation (non-empty) for Radio Buttons
$('#rom > li.active').find('input:radio').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('li').find('button.next').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
});});
```

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a snippet here

Comment: What is `closest(button.next)` supposed to do? You need quotes there too and closest is going up the dom

Comment: Why are you using keyup? The event will never fire on a mouse click

Comment: Yeah, my "closest" bit here is a fail. Yet it's not what does not work.

Comment: No error on the console. On DevTools, a loop seems to occur in the jQuery code..

Comment: Sorry, the Input field validation has not really been taken care of (it's the third li and I'm stuck on the second one, that's why). It's all nonsense.

Comment: In the demo I'm not even getting to a second question, not working at all for me

Comment: Is it normal the external resources got nullified? The jQuery got lost somehow.. Sorry

Comment: I'm working on it locally

Comment: First question does work on the updated fiddle now

Comment: Why are you appending your buttons instead of just having them in the HTML to start? Is that a requirement?

Comment: Ok your targeting seems all wrong, do you mind if I completely rework your code?

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me. Reworking is obviously ok. I guess I should have reviewed my jQuery basics before posting this.

Comment: So this line is the problem, the radio button click is not being detected. I'm working on it $('#rom .active').find('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
      console.log("working");
      $(this).closest('li').find('button.next').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok change your validation code to this

```
 $('input').click(function(){

      var checkBoxes = $('.active input[type="checkbox"]');
      if($(this).is(':radio')){
        console.log("radio");
        $(this).closest('li').find('button.next').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
      }else if($(this).is(':checkbox') && $(this).is(':checked')){
        console.log("checkbox");
        $(this).closest('li').find('button.next').prop('disabled', checkBoxes.filter(':checked').length < 1);

      }

    });
```

And change your keyup code to this

```
  $('.input-group input').keyup(function() {
  console.log("keyup");

    var empty = false;

        if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
            empty = true;
          console.log("empty true");
        }

    if (empty) {
        $(this).closest('.active').find('.next').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    } else {
        $(this).closest('.active').find('.next').attr('disabled', false).css("display","inline-block");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You were also right to add the conditional `&& $(this).is(':checked')`. Yet I can check a checkbox then uncheck it and still be able to click on "next".. wondering why. This is going to be my next assignment!

Comment: The reason you can still click on next is because there isn't any logic to disable the button again once it's been enabled

Comment: Yep, I figured this out and went for a leaner conditional: `if(('checkBoxes:checked').length > 0)` seems to be sufficient for the checkbox check